# Ajax responseText comes back as undefined

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm having problems with this piece of code; the return value comes back as 'undefined'. What's the problem?

```
var fx = null;
xmlhttp.open("GET", URL ,false);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() 
    {
        alert("enter func");            
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) 
        {
        if (xmlhttp.status == 200) 
            {                   
                alert(fx);                  
                fx = xmlhttp.responseText;
                return fx;
            }
        else
            {
                alert("Error" + xmlhttp.statusText);
            }
        }
    }
```

Newer code:

```
function getData(callback)
 {      
    xmlhttp.open("GET", URL ,false);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() 
        {               
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) 
            {
            if (xmlhttp.status == 200) 
                {                   
                    alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
                    cbfunc(xmlhttp.responseText);                   
                }
            else
                {
                    alert("Error" + xmlhttp.statusText);
                }
        }
    }   
        xmlhttp.send(null);
 }
```

How I'm calling it:

```
getData( function cbfoo(txt)
         {
            //document.form.autodate.value=txt;
            alert(txt);
            alert(document.form.autodate.value);
         });`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update based on your edit**

```
function getData(callback)
 {       
    // you should  move the creation of xmlhttp in here
    // so you can make multiple getData calls if needed 
    // if you keep xmlhttp outside the function the different calls to getData will interfere 
    // with each other

    xmlhttp.open("GET", URL ,false); // false should be true, to make it async
    ...
                {                   
                    alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
                    cbfunc(xmlhttp.responseText); // your function gets passed as the 
                                                  // parameter "callback" but you're 
                                                  // using "cbfunc" here instead of "callback"
 ...
 getData(function cbfoo(txt) // you can omit the function name here
 ...
```

Fixing those issues should make the code work.

**Old answer**

You're calling the XMLHttpRequest in **Synchronous** mode, that means that it will **block** the script until the request has finished, since you're assigning the `onreadystatechange` callback after the blocking call (that means after the request has already finished) your code never gets notified.

Since the synchronous mode blocks the script, it also blocks the Browser's UI, so it's not recommended to use this mode.

You should (for 99% of the cases) use the **Asynchronous** mode and use a callback to handle the data, since `xmlhttp.open` does **not** return the return value of the `onreadystatechange` callback, it simply returns `undefined` immediately when run in async mode.

Now a common pattern is to write a wrapper for the request and pass an **anonymous** function to this wrapper, which later will get called back when the request has finished.

```
function doRequest(url, callback) {
    var xmlhttp = ....; // create a new request here

    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true); // for async
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {     
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) {
            if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {

                // pass the response to the callback function
                callback(null, xmlhttp.responseText);

            } else {
                // pass the error to the callback function
                callback(xmlhttp.statusText);
            }
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.send(null);
}
```

You can now do a request and supply a function that will get called as soon as the request finishes, inside of that function you then do whatever you want to do with the response.

```
doRequest('http://mysite.com/foo', function(err, response) { // pass an anonymous function
    if (err) {
        alert('Error: ' + err);

    } else {
        alert('Response: ' + response);
    } 
});
```

This is the common programming model in the browser, always go with a asynchronous solution, if you block the script you block the whole Browser.

Comment: Actually `xmlhttp.open("GET", URL ,false);` makes the call synchronous so onreadystatechange may never fire. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536648(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Hemlock Dang, that's what you get from always using jquery... gonna adjust my answer for that.

Comment: @Ivo Wetzel Best response ever

Comment: The thing is, I'm actually getting the value I need from the servlet I'm calling up, the only problem is when it's actually returning it outside the onreadystatechange function. Sorry for omitting this piece of info. If I put up a var inside the function and check it with an alert prior to returning, I get what I need. After that, I just get 'undefined'.

Comment: @RedForeman There is no "outside return" in your code, you can't access the return value of the `onreadystatechange` callback. How does you assignment look like?

Comment: @Ivo Wetzel My assignment is basically var foo = func(), and that code I put in the OP is inside. And it returns undefined :(

Comment: @RedForeman But what is `func()`, also have you tried the pattern I've suggested in my answer? Since it is the normal way of doing such requests.

Comment: @RedForeman Don't sweat it I'm sure we're going to get it to work :)

Comment: So basically what I'm doing right now is this: I have an init() function I call when the page loads; this in turn calls the function with the ajax functions. If xmlhttp.status == 200, I make it call the callback function with xmlhttp.responseText as a parameter.

foo( function cbfoo(txt)
   {
   //document.form.autodate.value=txt;
   alert(txt);
   alert(document.formulario.fxAuto.value);
   });

That's basically what I'm doing in the init function. But nothing's showing up right now.

Comment: @RedForment Would you mind editing your question and post the complete code so I could get a better picture of it? :)