# AJAX - Return responseText

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest, scope

I've seen the myriad threads sprawled across the Internet about the following similar code in an AJAX request returning undefined:

```
AJAX.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(AJAX.readyState == 4) {
            if(AJAX.status == 200) {
                var response = AJAX.responseText;
                return response;
            }
            else {
                window.alert('Error: ' + AJAX.status);
                return false;
            }
        }
};
```

I know that I'm supposed to "do something with" `responseText` like writing it to the HTML. The problem: **I don't have that luxury**. This bit of code is intended to be inside of a generic method for running fast AJAX requests that way all the code for making an AJAX request doesn't have to written out over and over again (~40×) with the chance of a minor problem here or there that breaks the application.

My method *HAS* to explicitly `return responseText` "or else." ***No writing to HTML.*** How would I do this? Also, I'd appreciate a lack of plugs for JQuery.

What I'm looking for:

```
function doAjax(param) {
    // set up XmlHttpRequest
    AJAX.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(AJAX.readyState == 4) {
                if(AJAX.status == 200) {
                    var response = AJAX.responseText;
                    return response;
                }
                else {
                    window.alert('Error: ' + AJAX.status);
                    return false;
                }
            }
    };
    // send data
}
...
function doSpecificAjax() {
    var param = array();
    var result = doAjax(param);
    // manipulate result
}
```

Comment: Could you explain further what "No writing to HTML" means?

Comment: As in no writing the result to a `div` as a means of storage for the value.

Comment: So then, could you just return "" if responseText has nothing?

Comment: If I try to use the method that contains this: `var result = doAJAX();` then `result` equates to `undefined`

Comment: Are you opposed to using jQuery for your generic method?

Comment: Yes, and so is the company I work for. The application also has 56k'ers and people with limited bandwidth in mind, which means cutting out unnecessary libraries like jQuery. Which is why I asked _not to see JQuery promotions_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing a little research I came across this SOF post: 
[Ajax responseText comes back as undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672691/ajax-responsetext-comes-back-as-undefined)

Based on that post, it looks like you may want to implement your ajax method like this:

```
function doRequest(url, callback) {
    var xmlhttp = ....; // create a new request here

    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true); // for async
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {     
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) {
            if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {

                // pass the response to the callback function
                callback(null, xmlhttp.responseText);

            } else {
                // pass the error to the callback function
                callback(xmlhttp.statusText);
            }
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.send(null);
}
```

Then, you can call that method like this...

```
doRequest('http://mysite.com/foo', function(err, response) { // pass an anonymous function
    if (err) {
        return "";

    } else {
        return response;
    } 
});
```

This should return the responseText accurately.  Let me know if this doesn't give you back the correct results.

Comment: Thanks! This keeps me from having to repeat whole query setups every time I want to perform one.

Comment: @DissidentRage - Glad to hear it.