# AJAX response text undefined

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am following below 2 posts:

1. [Ajax responseText comes back as undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672691/ajax-responsetext-comes-back-as-undefined)
2. [Can't return xmlhttp.responseText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10369839/cant-return-xmlhttp-responsetext)

I have implemented the code in same fashion. But I am getting

> undefined is not a function

wherever i am using callback() funtion in my code.

CODE:

```
function articleLinkClickAction(guid,callback){

    var host = window.location.hostname;
    var action = 'http://localhost:7070/assets/find';
    var url = action + '?listOfGUID=' + guid.nodeValue;
    console.log("URL "+url);
    xmlhttp = getAjaxInstance();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

            var response = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
            console.log(response);
            console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
            callback(null, xmlhttp.responseText);// this is line causing error
        }
        else{
            callback(xmlhttp.statusText);// this is line causing error
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
}
```

And I am calling it from this code:

```
var anchors =  document.getElementsByTagName("a");
        var result = '';
        for(var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
            var anchor = anchors[i];

            var guid = anchor.attributes.getNamedItem('GUID');
            if(guid)
            {
                articleLinkClickAction(guid,function(err, response) { // pass an anonymous function
                    if (err) {
                        return "";

                    } else {
                        var res =  response;
                        html = new EJS({url:'http://' + host + ':1010/OtherDomain/article-popup.ejs'}).render({price:res.content[i].price});
                        document.body.innerHTML += html;
                    } 
                });
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please post your code. We need to see what and how you did.

Comment: Guyz i have added the code. Please see and help me.

Comment: @Abhi so do you mean **callback** can not used with template ?

Comment: @maxspan any clue/correction ?

Comment: check the null value (err) passed in ur callback..

Comment: @AwRak nope, it is just a "" string.

Comment: If it's a string then there was an error. (Otherwise it would have been a null)

Comment: @SecondRikudo but what could be that error ?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a single global variable for your `xmlhttp` and trying to run multiple ajax calls at the same time.  As such each successive ajax call will overwrite the previous ajax object.

I'd suggest adding `var` in front of the `xmlhttp` declaration to make it a local variable in your function so each ajax request can have its own separate state.

```
function articleLinkClickAction(guid,callback){

    var host = window.location.hostname;
    var action = 'http://localhost:7070/assets/find';
    var url = action + '?listOfGUID=' + guid.nodeValue;
    console.log("URL "+url);
    // add var in front of xmlhttp here to make it a local variable
    var xmlhttp = getAjaxInstance();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

            var response = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
            console.log(response);
            console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
            callback(null, xmlhttp.responseText);// this is line causing error
        }
        else{
            callback(xmlhttp.statusText);// this is line causing error
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
}
```

In the future, you should consider using [Javascript's `strict` mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) because these "accidental" global variables are not allowed in strict mode and will report an error to make you explicitly declare all variables as local or global (whichever you intend).

I can't say if this is the only error stopping your code from working, but it is certainly a significant error that is in the way of proper operation.

---

Here's another significant issue.  In your real code (seen in a private chat), you are using:

```
document.body.innerHTML += html
```

in the middle of the iteration of an HTMLCollection obtained like this:

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
```

In this code, `anchors` will be a live HTMLCollection.  That means it will change dynamically anytime an anchor element is added or removed from the document.  But, each time you do `document.body.innerHTML += html` that recreates the entire body elements from scratch and thus completely changes the `anchors` `HTMLCollection`.   Doing `document.body.innerHTML += html` in the first place is just a bad practice.  Instead, you should append new elements to the existing DOM.  I don't know exactly what's in that html, but you should probably just create a div, put the HTML in it and append the div like this:

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = html;
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

But, this isn't quite all yet because if this new HTML contains more `<a>` tags, then your live HTMLCollection in `anchors` will still change.

I'd suggestion changing this code block:

```
    var anchors =  document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    var result = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
        var anchor = anchors[i];

        var guid = anchor.attributes.getNamedItem('GUID');
        if(guid)
        {
            articleLinkClickAction(guid,function(err, response) { // pass an anonymous function
                if (err) {
                    return "";

                } else {
                    var res =  response;
                    html = new EJS({url:'http://' + host + ':1010/OtherDomain/article-popup.ejs'}).render({price:res.content[i].price});
                    document.body.innerHTML += html;
                } 
            });
        }
    }
```

to this:

```
(function() {
    // get static copy of anchors that won't change as document is modified
    var anchors = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("a"));

    var result = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
        var anchor = anchors[i];

        var guid = anchor.attributes.getNamedItem('GUID');
        if (guid) {
            articleLinkClickAction(guid, function (err, response) { // pass an anonymous function 
                if (err) {
                    //return ""; 
                    console.log('error : ' + err);
                } else {
                    var res = response;
                    var html = new EJS({
                        url: 'http://' + host + ':1010/OtherDomain/article-popup.ejs'
                    }).render({
                        price: res.content[i].price
                    });
                    var div = document.createElement("div");
                    div.innerHTML = html;
                    document.body.appendChild(html);
                }
            });
        }
    }
})();
```

This makes the following changes:

1. Encloses the code in an IIFE (self executing function) so the variables declared in the code block are not global.
2. Changes from `document.body.innerHTML += html` to use `document.body.appendChild()` to avoid recreating all the DOM elements every time.
3. Declares `var html` so it's a local variable, not another accidental global.
4. Makes a copy of the result from `document.getElementsByTagName("a")` using `Array.prototype.slice.call()` so the array will not change as the document is modified, allowing us to accurately iterate it.

Comment: you mean at this line  xmlhttp = getAjaxInstance();

Comment: @mahendrakawde - yes, as the code in my answer now shows.

Comment: @mahendrakawde - then you must have some additional issue because this one certainly needs fixing.  What line of code are you getting the `undefined is not a function` error on?

Comment: callback(null, xmlhttp.responseText);// this is line causing error
callback(xmlhttp.statusText);// this is line causing error
These are the lines causing an error

Comment: @mahendrakawde - there must be more going on than the code in your question discloses because the code you show would not cause that error on that line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75087/discussion-between-mahendrakawde-and-jfriend00).